# @HttpExchange with more webclient

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

Hi how can I set webclient to specific @HttpExchange interface?

I have 2 webclient(diferent hosts) service1 and service 2 but  also I have 2 diferent interfaces How should I define the correct WebClient for an interface (@HttpExchange)?

```
...
@HttpExchange(
        url = "/api/v1/s1",
        accept = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public interface UserIntegration {

    @GetExchange
    User getUser (@RequestParam("Id") String id);

}
...

  @Bean("s1WebClient")
    public WebClient webS1Client() {

        return WebClient
                .builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .defaultStatusHandler(httpStatusCode -> HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND == httpStatusCode, response -> Mono.empty())
                .defaultStatusHandler(HttpStatusCode::is5xxServerError, response -> Mono.error(new IntegrationException("Faild")))
                .build();

    }
```

```
...
@HttpExchange(
        url = "/api/v1/s2",
        accept = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public interface UserIntegration {

    @GetExchange
    Role getRole (@RequestParam("Id") String id);

}
...
  @Bean("s2WebClient")
    public WebClient webS2Client() {

        return WebClient
                .builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .defaultStatusHandler(httpStatusCode -> HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND == httpStatusCode, response -> Mono.empty())
                .defaultStatusHandler(HttpStatusCode::is5xxServerError, response -> Mono.error(new IntegrationException("Faild")))
                .build();

    }
```